# Casting with application not in Chrome

Tags: chromecast

Does the SDK allow me to cast from a straight windows application, rather than from the Chrome browser?  I want to upgrade our application to include casting a particular form and sound to the TV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it doesn't allow that; there is no SDK for such approach.

Comment: That's really unfortunate.  Many, many more apps could use this feature in their offering...